# How can I run a background PHP script on a hosting account like godaddy?

Tags: php, cpanel, godaddy, cron

I need to run a PHP script 24x7 on the server I'll be hosting my website on (Probably Godaddy). The PHP script's job is to open a socket and wait for incoming  connections. Once a connection is established, it receives some data from 'Somewhere' and pushes it to a database. The data from this database will be constantly accessed by my index.php and will be used accordingly having some particular frequency.

The code is all ready and is working perfectly on my LAN using WAMP. But I am absolutely clueless on going about doing this in hosting accounts. I am guessing SSH, cron and cPanel is the way but no idea on how to do it and connect. Please elaborate the entire process and suggest some readings.

Comment: Does the script require super privileges to be executed ? With any shared hosting account you will get jailed shell access. If it required root privileges, you won't be able to execute it in shared hosting environment.

Comment: Even then, most hosts will not allow you to run an unknown or unauthorized network service which is what you are describing. Certainly not on a shared server. It is a security risk.

Comment: If it so, what else can i do? Get a static ip and host this project through my own PC? Any other way around this? @closetnoc

Comment: Some hosts may allow it, but it will be on a dedicated server. I used to be a web host. I would only allow it after a code review. Most hosts will not do a code review. There are web hosts that are designed for a more professional level of service and not for the masses. Keep that in mind. Most that are designed for the masses will either say no because it does not fit their business model or say yes because they are low quality and do not care. Some are very capable of handling these types of requests. But your code must be solid.

Comment: That was very valuable! Thanks a lot! okay so lets just say that they have reviewed it and gave the green signal. Whats next? How to actually run the script continuously in background? Would it be really long cron jobs? or some strange things called daemons? @closetnoc

Comment: It would not be a cron job. Cron is for scheduling tasks to run periodically. You would have to write the code to run continuously and handle certain signals. You would have it load on boot. You would test by opening a window and executing it there. I do know PHP at all. It is not really designed for that, but may work anyway. Keep in mind that security is a huge factor and you will really need to know what you are doing. You can learn on the fly, but do not make it live until you know what you are doing and your code is solid.

Comment: I am delighted that you helped. Thanks for the insight! Guess i'll have to figure out a different way. @closetnoc

Comment: Or learn to code a network service. It is tougher than most things, however, with enough time, you can do it. You just have to dig in. Some of my very first code were protocol stacks and device drivers. We all learn by doing of course. Challenges are encouraged. Certainly, you will be a stronger programmer just for trying! Cheers!!

Comment: Yeah, @closetnoc is right.  You'd have to learn to write a daemon and would likely need your own server.  I run a web hosting company and I wouldn't allow it on my server.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)

Answer (score 1):

Many hosting companies have in their terms and conditions bans on any background processes which just sit there waiting for connections, additionally they firewalls servers against incoming connections on ports not used as standard on the server for what they believe the server should be used for. As I recall GoDaddy has this restriction on all shared and semi-shared hosting services and only allows this on virtual servers or dedicated servers. To do what you are wanting to do you would need to have a virtual server or dedicated server hosting account which will give you a greater level of access to the server itself and will avoid the strict restrictions applied to shared servers.